# php session my post variable

Tags: php, post

My `index.php` file performs operations on variables and if query has been succes, going to the `zamowienie.php` file. How can I now use these variables in the `zamowienie.php` file?

```
$kwota2 = $_POST['kwota2'];
$zamowienie2 = $_POST['zamowienie2'];
$var = $_POST['taskOption'];
$nr_zamowienia2 = $_POST['nr_zamowienia2'];
```

so How can I pass them on to the session?

```
require_once "../produkty/php/connect.php";

        try {
            $polaczenie = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
            if ($polaczenie->connect_errno != 0) {
                throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_errno());
            } else {
                $polaczenie = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

                $kwota2 = $_POST['kwota2'];
                $zamowienie2 = $_POST['zamowienie2'];
                $var = $_POST['taskOption'];
                $nr_zamowienia2 = $_POST['nr_zamowienia2'];

                if ($polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO zamowienia VALUES ('$nr_zamowienia2', '$zamowienie2', '$kwota2', '$var', 'Oczekiwanie')")) {
                    header('Location: zamowienie.php');
                }
            }

            $polaczenie->close();
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: it is not necessary. how can I save the above variables in a session?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: I've given you an example but this seems like something you can really easily find in the documentation.

Comment: You check if the connection failed, and if it didn't, connect again..?

Answer (score 0):

Pass them on the session, I am guessing you're talking about assigning the `$_POST` values to your `$_SESSION`.

It works just like any normal variable:

```
$_SESSION['kwota2'] = $_POST['kwota2'];
```

Your `$_SESSION` variable is an array, and you simply assign a key between the `['']` brackets.

Then if you want to use it just:

```
echo $_SESSION['kwota2'];
```

Or whatever you need to do with it.

---

Don't forget to initiate your session (`session_start()`)

Answer (score 0):

To save session variables, you need to start the session then save the variable to the session vars.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'] = $whateverYouWantToUse;
```

Or perhaps if you want to save post to session, you can do something like.

```
$_SESSION['SessVar'] = $_POST['postVar'];
```

Just a note, session vars are secure and post are not, and by making a session var equal directly to a post var can cause security problems.

Then in the next file.

```
session_start();
print($_SESSION['variable]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['kwota2'];
$_SESSION['b'] = $_POST['zamowienie2'];
$_SESSION['cc'] = $_POST['taskOption'];
$_SESSION['aa'] = $_POST['nr_zamowienia2'];
```